# Do NJT buses accept more than exact change?

Tags: transportation, new-york-city, new-jersey

I'm considering taking NJT bus 62 to the airport from the West Village (in combination with the PATH train, which takes Metrocards, so that's easy). I've see online that the bus accepts only exact change (conflicting information on the actual fare, [this schedule](http://www.njtransit.com/pdf/bus/T0062.pdf) says it's $1.60, I've read slightly over $2 on the internet, regardless, it's "cheap", whatever).

Does this mean that I need to actually have coins with me, or will they accept e.g. $2 if the fare is $1.60? Or, for 3 people, $5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you can buy the bus or train ticket through MYTIX app, so you don't have to keep exact fare or overpay them,

Just download the app into your smart phone, buy the ticket online before you board in or when you can get into the bus and request him to give you 2-3 mins so you can buy your ticket.

i hope this will help you to save money.

link: http://www.njtransit.com/mytix

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can pay more than the required fare.  I overpaid my fare several months ago.  The trip passed without incident.  (What do you imagine the driver would do, refuse to transport you for overpaying?)

Comment: Never underestimate the doggedness of the bureaucratic mind ;-)

Comment: @djna basically that